# Is the length of a distributed Bragg reflector $= λ / 4$ so that one mirror is at a maximum?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, fiber-optics

Am I correct in my assumption that the ideal length for a [distributed Bragg reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Bragg_reflector) (DBR) is the wavelength of light over 4, so that one of the mirrors is at a maximum for each photon... and this makes it less likely to transmit across because the wave uses its energy pushing on the charges in the mirror?

thus making a stopband for that wavelength of light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the ideal layer thickness (not length). The reason is because of constructive interference not charge (excepting that light is an electromagnetic wave and inherently involves charge), and will occur for all waves (eg in pipes for acoustics). There will also be constructive interference at higher harmonics (integer multiples of the frequency).

You also shouldn't talk about mirrors. There are typically not coatings for a distributed Bragg reflector but a periodic index change. Also note that the wavelength in question is the wavelength in the medium which is different to the free space wavelength.